# Remove Unused Javascript

Tags: reactjs, heroku, next.js

When we run our app that has been built on nextjs and is hosted on Heroku through Lighthouse and we keep getting a warning saying to "Remove unused JavaScript".

Two of the javascript files listed to be removed are:

1. https://widgetbe.com/widget
2. https://widgetbe.com/agent

We don't host this code anywere whithin our app including our dependencies. How can I ensure that 1) these are not malicious files that somehow made it into this project and 2) remove them

Comment: Can you share the url which loads these 2 files? You can check Chrome Developer Console on Network Tab for file loading details.

Comment: Hey @L.fole here's the url https://felix-staging.herokuapp.com/. I do see the script being called in the network tab however I have no idea how that's possible. Furthermore a little google investigation reveals that other real estate sites have this issue as well (unknowingly perhaps)

 https://www.google.com/search?ei=37eFX67ADM-Q_Qa8_YCwCw&q=%22widgetbe.com%2Fagent%22&oq=%22widgetbe.com%2Fagent%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoHCAAQRxCwA1DOiQFYiKQBYIOmAWgBcAB4AIABsQGIAZ0JkgEDMC43mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjuq6aH4rHsAhVPSN8KHbw-ALYQ4dUDCA0&uact=5

Comment: turns out somehow these scripts made it into our google tag manager